# pip3 hangs while pip works

Tags: python, pip

I had Python 2.7.9 installed at D:\Python27 and running for a long time already, and today I installed Python 3.4.4 at D:\Python34. Both paths and their relevant Scripts folder are in the PATH environment variable, but whenever I try to use `pip3` it just hangs (`pip` works just fine).

Any idea what's going on? System is windows 10 64-bit if it matters.

Comment: very interesting...works fine with debian linux....have you tried pip3 with command line arguments?

Comment: @repzero Yeah I did but it still hangs.

Comment: Does it happen from every directory?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes it does. Even I open a cmd window at D:\Python34\Scripts and run pip3.exe it just hangs, as if the exe itself is corrupted (but it keeps happening, no mater how many times I re-install Python 3).

Comment: You don't have any other pip3 executable in your path? What does `python3 -m pip --version` output?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No, although both folders (Python27 and Python34) have pip.exe, the 27 folder has pip.exe, pip2.7.exe and pip2.exe, and the 34 folder has pip.exe, pip3.4.exe and pip3.exe. The rest of the folders in PATH (non-Python related) has no pip.exe or similiar. 

Every `pip` I'm trying to use (pip2, pip2.7, pip3 or pip3.4) except for 'pip.exe' hangs

Comment: does `python3 -m pip --version` hang?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No, `python3 -m pip --version` actually works, thanks :). Would you please post it as an answer so I can mark it as correct for future reference?

Comment: @DeepSpace, I think there is definitely some other dodgy executable in the path, what did `python3 -m pip --version` return?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham `pip 7.1.2 from D:\Python34\lib\site-packages (python 3.4)`

Comment: Can you open up the pip's in the python3 scripts folder and see what is inside?

Comment: It has these 3 exe files I mentioned, which contain a `__main__.py` file with this code: `if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0]) ; 
    sys.exit(main())`

Comment: One last thing, I am not overly familiar with windows but does `where` act like which in linux? i,e can you do `where pip3`?

Comment: "where pip" outputs `D:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe D:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe`, and "where pip3" outputs `D:\Python34\Scripts\pip3.exe`

Comment: so `D:\Python34\Scripts\pip3.exe --version` also hangs?

Comment: Strange, ok one very last thing, inside `D:\Python34\Scripts\pip3.exe` add a `print("Called")` and `import pip;print(pip.__file__)` at the start of the script